# Browserify require sibling file from an npm repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I have a certain module I would like to require in my .js file. The module has 2 files a.js and b.js as siblings, a.js being the main file in package.json.

Both a.js and b.js are available via module.exports. However when I use

```
require("mymodule")
```

I get a.js. I also need b.js to be required.
Also , a.js is not importing b.js in anyway.
I searched the net for a solution but dint find one. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How does `a` try to require `b`?

Comment: a does not require b. they are two different implementations of the same api. I need b not a, but a happens to be the main file.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you expect the end result to be. Do you want both modules be included in a single file? If yes then you need to have a file which includes both.

Comment: No. I just need to require b.js somehow from the npm module.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. If `require("mymodule")` should load b.js, then change package.json to point to b.js.

Comment: But it would not be a permanent solution right? Please correct me if I am wrong. When I update the module, package.json might be overridden and this would become a repeating exercise. I was hoping for a solution which would load a file based on its relative position from the main file in the repository.

Comment: So it's not your own module? It's a third party module? I guess you want `require('mymodule/b')` then.

Comment: Yeah, it is a third party module. But then mymodule/b dint work.

Comment: Then the structure of the module is not how you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to require b directly with `require('mymodule/b')`, but if that doesn't work, you can always require it by path, like `require('./node_modules/mymodule/b')` (obviously, adjust the "./" to be appropriate for the location of node_modules relative to the file you're in).

Comment: I just saw the first part of this answer was suggested in comments above (it was hidden by default under "More comments" when I first read this). That really _should_ work. What module is it you're trying to require? A concrete example will be easier to debug.